# Remote Linux Server setup plan

Tags: linux, remote-access

I have an old computer with formatted drive lying around collecting dust, now I want to instal a linux like OS (any suggestions?) on it and install a web server, preferrably Lighttpd.  I want to set up a server so that I have an environment to practice web development in PHP or Java.  My problem is I dont want to hook up another set of keyboard/mouse/monitor to that old computer, and if possible I want to remote boot/shutdown the server from this computer that I use to type this question.

I did some google search, but the results are never comprehensive or suitable for my circumstance.  Any input would be appreciated, book recommendation or link to a good resource are fine too.

Thanks

Qin

P.S. I did some search on stackoverflow before asking this question, if there is another similiar question being asked, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually needs an unattended (silent) linux installation, which may trigger beeps to tell you when the installation is done. Hope this can help you refine your search on google.

Answer (score 0):

You'll definitely need at least a monitor or KVM and a keyboard if you want to install any OS on it.

For server OS, you could try going for CentOS / Ubuntu. However, if your requirement is just to practice your PHP and Java, you could even use your existing laptop / PC and, assuming windows, you can just install [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/) or [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), to install your apache/php/mysql with just **clicks**.